Why is the math outputting incorrectly?
I wrote a code to change decimal numbers to binary numbers on 2 different compilers, dev c++ and codeblock.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int n=0, nhiphan=0, m=0, thuong=0, du=0;
    scanf("%i", &n);

    while(n>0){
        du=n%2;
        nhiphan = nhiphan + (du)*pow(10,m);
        m++;
        thuong = n/2;
        n=thuong;
    }
    printf("%i\n", nhiphan);
}

When I tried 6 the dev c give the correct answer which is 110 but the code block gives the output is 109 even my online judge gave the wrong answer I had checked others number on dev c it still give the correct answer but the codeblock sometimes give wrong answers.
Is there a way to check how it works and how to prevent it from giving the wrong answer?

pow returns a double, so I expect you have rounding errors. Instead, start m at 1, and multiply it by 10 each time through the loop.

Using a (32 bit) int to represent a binary number in base 10 only works for binary numbers with up to 10 bits (so up to 2047) before you get an overflow.

@PaulHankin: Re “pow returns a double, so I expect you have rounding errors”: These are not rounding errors. 10^m is exactly representable in the format commonly used for double for non-negative m up to 22, so there is no need to round the result. If pow does not return 10^m for these cases, it is because it was implemented incorrectly, not because floating-point requires rounding.

Do not work with binary by trying to encode it as digits 0 and 1 in a decimal numeral. That is wasteful and quite limited by the int width. Doing scanf("%i", &n) converts decimal input to binary; the result is in binary in n. Just test its bits and directly print “0” or “1”.

@EricPostpischil, it is relatively common for FP libraries to implement functions that sometimes produce results that are incorrectly rounded, within some error bound. Within 1 ulp, say.  This being done intentionally, usually for speed, makes "rounding error" a better description than "incorrectly implemented" in my book. That the correctly rounded result is an exact result is not relevant to this analysis if the error bound is at least 1 ulp, which is not so uncommon for pow() implementations.

@JohnBollinger: Such libraries should be regarded as incorrectly implemented. If you had an integer division function that sometimes returned a quotient too high, that would be regarded as an incorrect implementation. If you had a linked list function that sometimes dropped an element from the list, that would be regarded as an incorrect implementation. A function that returns a result that is not the correct result when the correct result can be returned is incorrectly implemented.

@EricPostpischil, if those hypothetical integer division, etc functions were behaving as they were designed to do, then that would be best characterized as "poorly designed" not "incorrectly implemented".  A pow() function that is designed to return a result within 1ulp of the correctly rounded result cannot be faulted as incorrect when it returns a result that differs from the correctly rounded one by 1 ulp.  You can find fault with such a pow() design if you like, but the fact is that such designs are common, and one needs to be aware of that when working with fp math.

@EricPostpischil would you also consider, say pow(9, 0.5) to be incorrectly implemented if it does not return exactly 3? Or if pow(0.25, 0.5) does not return exacly 0.5, etc.?

Glibc, for example, specifies a 1ulp error bound  for pow() on most architectures, including i686 and x86_64.

@WeatherVane: Yes.

@JohnBollinger: The fact a library specifies an error bound does not mean we should accept it. If a sort routine specified it often sorted everything correctly but occasionally had two elements swapped, I would acknowledge that it conformed to its specifications but would not accept it as a properly implemented sort routine. The state of the art in floating-point math libraries has advanced. There are good open-source implementations. One should insist on at least the quality of publicly available source code.

Yet by and large, the community does accept it for FP functions, @EricPostpischil.  It is a reasonable design decision in the FP regime to trade off a tiny bit of accuracy in exchange for speed, because many applications need the speed more than they need the accuracy, and one cannot, in general, expect exact FP results anyway.  If one requires FP functions that always return the correctly-rounded result then one can get them, but that one needs to pay attention to that is one of the details that anyone programming with FP needs to bear in mind.

@JohnBollinger: Re “Yet by and large, the community does accept it for FP functions”: Don’t. Times change. New code is available. New proofs have been made. The prevalence of people accepting bad code is not a reason to join them. Re “It is a reasonable design decision in the FP regime to trade off a tiny bit of accuracy in exchange for speed”: It was a reasonable design decision decades ago. Times change. There is new code, and it provides good performance at high accuracy, sometimes even better performance than old code with less accuracy. Stop accepting bad code.

@EricPostpischil, certainly advances are made, but as far as I can determine, the particular advance you want here has not been made.  Consider this 2024 paper presenting an efficient, correctly-rounded pow() implementation that compares quite well to other correctly-rounded implementations.  The authors seem enthusiastic that it is only 26% slower than glibc's within-1-ulp pow().

Ultimately, it gives the wrong impression to call a pow() such as the OP's "incorrectly implemented".  It suggests that you should not expect such implementations, which is not good advice at this time.  On the other hand, that the result may not be correctly rounded is well described as it possibly containing rounding error, and encouraging programmers to maintain awareness of that possibility serves them well.

@JohnBollinger: Re “glibc's within-1-ulp pow()”: Glibc does not say it has a within-1-ULP pow. It says the maximum error is 1 ULP. That is a critical difference. If a routine returns a result within 1 ULP of the ideal mathematical result, then it returns exact results for representable values. If its maximum error is 1 ULP, not within 1 ULP, it may return incorrect results for representable values…

… In naïvely written code, the inaccuracy of pow implementations is more often a failure than performance is, as we have seen so often in Stack Overflow questions. In well-written code, pow is rarely heavily used, so a 26% slower implementation is a slight cost for more accuracy. (Not that I trust the glibc documentation. The statements “Ideally the error for all functions is always less than 0.5ulps in round-to-nearest mode. Using rounding bits this is also possible…” are false. The best the error bound can be is less than or equal to ½ ULP, and, again, this difference matters.)

@EricPostpischil, I disagree with you about the meaning of my wording, but the specific error bounds of Glibc's pow() are not the point.  I acknowledge that you would consider a 26% performance penalty acceptable under the circumstances, but (i) not everyone would agree, and (ii) that algorithm is brand new this year, so it hasn't factored into anyone's decision making yet.  If pow() generates an incorrectly rounded result then I don't see how one can deny that that is a rounding error.  Teaching that fp functions may have rounding errors serves inexperienced programmers well [...]

[...] whether you think they should have rounding errors or not.

@JohnBollinger: Re “If pow() generates an incorrectly rounded result then I don't see how one can deny that that is a rounding error”: Because it is not generally an incorrectly rounded result. The roundings involved in the calculation were likely done correctly, in accordance with IEEE 754 specification. The error is likely because it was incorrectly calculated or computed, by not using a polynomial calculated with the necessary accuracy or choosing not to use enough accuracy in the calculations to get a good answer. These things are choices, not happenstances or demands of floating-point.

@JohnBollinger: Re “Teaching that fp functions may have rounding errors serves inexperienced programmers well”: No, teaching inexperienced programmers they may get errors will serve them well. But they should be taught the causes of those errors are choices made by the implementors of the library routines, not a necessity of floating-point arithmetic. They should not be taught that those errors are caused by rounding errors; they should be taught they are caused by choices humans made.

@OP If the code is C++ why did you tag as [tag:c]? and not [tag:c++]?

I suggest adding and using your own implementation of pow(), because it seems that the variances of your output may be due to the various compilers having their own implementations of pow() that might be incompatible with your code.
This code uses its own implementation of pow() as ipow(), and is adapted from Elias Yarrkov's excellent contribution found here on stackoverflow.
Beyond that, I only modified your code slightly:

updated all ints to unsigned long long to ensure larger number handling, and
removed scanf() and directly assigned variable n to enable runnable code on godbolt.

Emphasis:  your code logic is unchanged: your code works.
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long ipow(unsigned long long base, unsigned long long exp)
{
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        if (!exp)
            break;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n=(255<<8)+255; /* Should give 1111111111111111 (16 ones)*/
    unsigned long long nhiphan=0, m=0, thuong=0, du=0;
    
    while(n>0)
    {
        du=n%2;
        nhiphan = nhiphan + (du)*ipow(10,m);
        m++;
        thuong = n/2;
        n=thuong;
    }
    printf("%llu\n", nhiphan);
}

Output:
    1111111111111111

Although you can take heart that your efforts and thinking worked, the above implementation is not the recommended solution.
This next implementation is better, imo.  It provides a string representation of the binary form of a number. It additionally provides nicer formatting which makes reading of the output easier on the eyes, and helps to ensure correctness of the output.
Runnable code is here.
#include <stdio.h>

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
    toBase2Str()
    Returns a string binary representation of an input number.
    Params: number to convert and the size of the data type
    so we know how many leading zeros to pad
*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
char *toBase2Str(unsigned long long num, size_t nsize)
{
    static char szRes[100];
    long iii=0, bitpos = nsize*8; 
    
    while (bitpos-- && iii < sizeof(szRes)-1) 
    {
        szRes[iii++] = (char) (((num >> bitpos) & 0x01) + '0'); 
        if(!(bitpos%8))
            szRes[iii++] = ' '; /*add space every 8 digits */
    }
    szRes[iii] ='\0'; /*cap it*/

    return szRes;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned char cnum = 0x0F;
    unsigned int  num = 0x0000FFFF;
    unsigned long long lnum = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    printf("%s \n", toBase2Str(cnum, sizeof(cnum)));
    printf("%s \n", toBase2Str(num, sizeof(num)));
    printf("%s \n", toBase2Str(lnum, sizeof(lnum)));
    return (0);
}

Output:
    00001111  
    00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111
    00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 


Do not do this. Computing binary in decimal is atrocious and completely unnecessary.

@EricPostpischil -- as usual, you are 100% correct.  However, with your permission, I would please ask that you let this stand for 2 reasons that seem good to me:  1.) it shows possibilities in C (though NOT best practice, no standards are actually violated and 2.) OP can take comfort in that his/her code works -- concept is correct.   OP can learn about better implementations and logic as he/she progresses in journey of C.
EDIT -- tell you what -- I will add a better implementation to help guide OP.
